# Unable to write in input tag in Xamarin MacOs Webview within a iframe

Tags: xamarin, webview

We have a Xamarin MacOs App that uses a webview to display web content.

The first page showed is a local html page text. That page have a iframe that point to a external web that its allowed to be embed like vimeo.

If that iframe have a input of type "text" and try to write in it, no keypress/keydown is fired, and then no text is write inside of the input.

Have extended WebKit.WebView to have access to native properties, but haven't found any preference to allow this.

The version used of Xamarin Forms is 5.0.0.2196

Have any a workaround for this strange scenario ?
Tx

### UPDATE 1

If press the keys "Control+tab", then input starts to receive input keys. So, the problem is that the control in iframe have focus, but the iframe in webview dont.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect any keyup events within the iframe. Here's the `HTML` & `JS` code snippets below for your reference:

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id='this-iframe'></iframe>
```

**JS:**

```
var iframe_content = '<html><body><input type="text" id="input_id"/><span id="result"></span></body></html>';
var doc = document.getElementById('this-iframe').contentWindow.document;
        doc.open();
        doc.write(iframe_content);
        doc.close();    
    
$(document.getElementById('this-iframe').contentWindow.document).keyup(function(e){
   if($('#this-iframe').contents().find('#input_id').is(":focus")){
      $('#this-iframe').contents().find("#result").html($('#this-iframe').contents().find('#input_id').val());
   }       
});
```

Comment: Tx for your help, but no one keypress is fired inside a iframe in a webview. Is like webview for MacOs block those events, that works in the main webview page.

Comment: You said you could get the input key via pressing `"Control+tab"`. Do you mean the iframe gets the focus when pressing `"Control+tab"`? If so, I think you can get the focus by pressing `"Control+tab"` directly or in back-end.